# Lambda on Python 3

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, lambda

I have a dataframe with 2 columns and I want to divide it in two arrays. I know that with Python 2 I could use this:

```
result = spark.sql("SELECT acoustic_data, time_to_failure from df order by acoustic_data asc")
result_rdd = result.rdd.sample(False, 0.0001).map(lambda row: (row.acoustic_data, row.time_to_failure))
result_signal = result_rdd.filter(lambda (acoustic_data, time_to_failure): acoustic_data).collect()
```

And the same with the other columns.

But if I try to do it now I get this error:

> TypeError: () missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'time_to_failure'

result_rdd return this:

[image: result_rdd]

So I want to take 2 arrays from it.

Greetings

Comment: Which line triggers the exception? Also what's with the parentheses on *lambda* (both definitions)?

Comment: The last line triggers it. YOu could use parenthesis to include both columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 3 [removed tuple parameter unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/), so this no longer works:

```
lambda (acoustic_data, time_to_failure): acoustic_data
```

Replace it with something like:

```
lambda acoustic_data_and_time_to_failure: acoustic_data_and_time_to_failure[0]
```